# initialize char matrix in class constructor

Tags: c++, oop, constructor, char

I need to initialize my variable in class constructor (because initializing it with declaration is bad, of course, although in works). I tried to initialize it with loop but I don't know how to do it properly. How can I solve this? Should I use pointers?

```
class Track
{
private:
    char track[18][19];
    /*

    need to initialize equal to
    track[18][19] = {
            "|               |",
            "|               |",
            "|               |",
            "|               |",
            "|               |",
            "|               |",
            "|               |",
            "|               |",
            "|               |",
            "|               |",
            "|               |",
            "|               |",
            "|               |",
            "|               |",
            "|               |",
            "|               |",
            "|               |",
            "|               |"
    };*/

public:

    Track(){
        for (int i=0; i<18; i++)
            for (int j = 1; j < 18; j++) {
                track[i][j] = ' ';
            }

        for (int i = 0; i < 18; i++) {
            track[i][0] = '|';
            track[i][sizeof(track[i]) / sizeof(track[i][0])] = '|';
        }
        //how to initialize track?
    }

    void Draw() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 18; i++) {
            cout << track[i] << endl;
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: You can use the constroctors member initializer list.

Comment: _because initializing it with declaration is bad_ says who?

Comment: What have you tried?  What did the code look like?

Comment: is there any reason you dont use a  `std::vector<std::string>` ?

Comment: Let me edit the post to show you
manni66 isn't it bad style? Correct me if not

Comment: No, it is not bad style.

Comment: tobi303 thanks a lot, your advice helped me

Answer (score 0):

It's recommended that you define `18` and `19` as constants:

```
const int LENGTH = 18;
const int WIDTH = 19;
```

You'd also need to have enough room for a NULL terminating character if you want your track sections to be printed properly:

```
char track[LENGTH][WIDTH + 1]; // (leave enough room for a NULL char)
```

As for your loop, you just need to add the NULL character to the end of each track section and use `WIDTH - 1` instead of attempting to calculate the index of the second-last character using `sizeof()`:

```
Track() {
    for (int i = 0; i < LENGTH; i++) {
        track[i][0] = '|';

        for (int j = 1; j < WIDTH - 1; j++) {
            track[i][j] = ' ';
        }

        track[i][WIDTH - 1] = '|';
        track[i][WIDTH] = '\0';
    }
}
```